# Derivative of $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}-x}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

How would I derivative this function?
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}-x}$$

The numerator derivative is: $$1$$

The denominator derivative is: $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-1$$

In the end, I get this weird equation: $4x^2 -7x+4$

Help please.

Comment: Please show how you get this "weird equation" (which might go for a "weird result").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice, we have $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt x-x}$$
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt x-x}\right)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{(\sqrt x-x)\frac{d}{dx}(x)-x\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt x-x)}{(\sqrt x-x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt x-x)(1)-x\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-1\right)}{(\sqrt x-x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt x-x-\frac{\sqrt x}{2}+x}{(\sqrt x-x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt x}{2(\sqrt x-x)^2}$$

Hence, 
$$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt x}{2(\sqrt x-x)^2}}}$$

Comment: I think the numerator has only $\sqrt{x}$, the 3 is not there.

Comment: Nice box in the end ;)

Comment: @Vaibhav: Thanks for observing the error.

Comment: This doesn't at all explain why OP got that weird result, and also, OP just got a solution thrown in his/her face. I'm waiting for the next question from OP with the same misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

Your numerator and denominator derivatives are correct.

Did you then use the rule

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)' = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}?$$